# Yii2 how to set Relation Alias

Tags: yii2

I have a Category table with a 'parent' column that refers to the same table. This gives me some hassle when i'm trying to update the GridView to show the parent category name instead of category parent id.

How do i define a relation alias in yii2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved:

I added the alias in the CategorySearch model:
It joins with the relation getParentCategory() and gives it the name parentCategory as an alias for 'category' table.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Category::find();

    $query->joinWith(['createdBy'])->joinWith(['parentCategory' => function($query) { $query->from(['parentCategory' => 'category']); }]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.username', $this->created_by])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parentCategory.name', $this->parent]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code.

/models/CategorySearch.php

```
$params['id'] = (int)$params['id'];
$query = Category::find()->where(['root' => $params['id']]);
```

Field `root` it is your field `parent`.

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Category;

/**
 * CategorySearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Category`.
 */
class CategorySearch extends Category
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'rank'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'description'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $params['id'] = (int)$params['id'];
        $query = Category::find()->where(['root' => $params['id']]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'rank' => $this->rank,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CategorySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```